# Can I use my Python or Conda environment of my Windows 10 on my Windows Subsystem Linux (WSL)?

Tags: python, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed and set up all my necessary lib and environment in my Windows OS.
I just install WSL and trying to code on WSL, and I wanna know whether I can reuse my available Windows's Python or Conda environment on WSL. If I can, how can I do that? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: Untested, but I would say that you cannot. Your Windows installation of Python contains Windows native executable and libraries (.exe and .dll files). AFAIK, WSL is a Linux environment, and it uses ELF executables and .so dynamic libraries. The configuration files and the plain Python files would probably be compatible but the binary files are not.